# Request factory in GWT, Library dependencies

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am newbie for GWT,and trying to understand the GWT request factory.

Moreover,I have been trying to run a Demo example of request factory from below link:
https://github.com/MikeMitterer/RFSample/

When I import it in Eclipse, there are so many libraries which are missing.

Like repackaged-appengine etc.

Can anyone help me to understand request factory. and why this libraries are required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heck that's the problem when you don't use *managed dependencies* (with tools such as Maven, Gradle or Ivy), you have to download everything by hand and edit the paths in the configuration to point to your downloaded JARs.

This sample apparently runs on AppEngine, so you'll have to download the Google AppEngine SDK. The author downloaded it (and the GWT SDK) separately, rather than using the Eclipse plugins from the Google Plugin for Eclipse. When done, edit the build path to fix the dependencies.

Back to Request Factory (rather than this sample), all you need is:

- in your Build Path: `gwt-user.jar` if you're build a GWT app, or `requestfactory-client.jar` if you're building a Java app (such as an Android client), along with `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` (and `validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar` if you're building a GWT app)
- in your `WEB-INF/lib`: `requestfactory-server.jar` or `gwt-servlet.jar`, along with `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` (you shouldn't need to add them to your build path though, all the classes they contain are already in gwt-user.jar); you might need gwt-servlet-deps.jar in addition to gwt-servlet.jar (can't remember, try it out)
- if you want to use bean validation, also include Hibernate Validator in your `WEB-INF/lib, but it's optional.
- Configure annotation processing with `requestfactory-apt.jar`, see https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation

And some links to understand it:

- http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html
- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-211-requestfactory and http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-211-requestfactory-part-ii
- https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryMovingParts

Comment: Yes that I knew it ,I will have to download them .But I wanted to know the basic understanding for why they are required.

Comment: @Mann "I wanted to know the basic understanding for why they are required": RequestFactory doesn't need AppEngine; that specific project apparently needs it, but that's specific to that project (and is thus not a good fit for StackOverflow, too specific). All the **required** JARs are in the GWT SDK; you can add a JSR 303-compatible validator (such as Hibernate Validator) if you want, but that's optional (and again, this specific project seems to be using it).